# iven $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+1}$, Find $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$, justify using limit definition at infinity

Tags: real-analysis

> Given $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+1}$, Find $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ if it exists. Justify using directly the following definition:
>
> $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=L$ if $f$ is defined on an interval $(a, \infty)$ and for each $\epsilon >0$ there is a number $\beta$ such that:
> $$| f(x) - L| < \epsilon $$ if $$x> \beta$$

First, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x^2+1} = \frac{1}{\infty}=0$

Second,
$$| f(x) - 0| = | \frac{1}{x^2+1}|< \epsilon$$
As $\frac{1}{x^2+1}>0$, we have:

$$\frac{1}{x^2+1}< \epsilon $$
$$1<\epsilon(x^2+1)$$

$$1<\epsilon x^2 + \epsilon$$
$$...$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}}<x$$

Therefore $L=0$ exists if $x>\sqrt{\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}}$

Is this correct? Is there anything that can be improved?

Any input is much appreciated

Comment: Assuming $\epsilon<1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reasoning is fine for $0 <\epsilon <1$. We have

$$ x>\sqrt{\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}} \implies \frac{1}{x^2+1}<\epsilon.$$

But the definition requires to consider **any** $\epsilon>0$.

For $\epsilon \geq 1$ you can choose $\beta=0$:

$$x>0 \implies \frac{1}{x^2+1}<\epsilon .$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also say:

$\frac{1}{x^2+1} \lt \frac{1}{x^2}\lt \epsilon$

Therefore $L=0$ when $x>\sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct. Please note that (as it has already been pointed out in the comments) your $\epsilon$ has to be smaller than $1$, otherwise picking an arbitrary $\epsilon >1$ would allow you to pick an $x$ arbitrarily small, which would contradict the conclusion (and you would get a negative square root, which you might want to avoid as well).

Furthermore the argument $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \frac{1}\infty$ only works here, because your function continuous.